# How to disable Rendering issue warning to xml in android studio

Tags: xml, android-layout, rendering

I want to know is there any option or setting to disable showing again and again warning to rendering issue in xml in android studio. It seems to be very annoying. I know in many case warning issue solved by changing themes but i even warning dont show to me. I have google it a lot but dont find any solution for that, all solution corresponding to solution to rendering problem but didnt find for its disablity.
Thank advance.